# Error trying to use mpi for a job on slurm cluster

Tags: python, mpi

I am trying to use when I submit a job to a university cluster but I get the message

> MPI startup(): PMI server not found. Please set I_MPI_PMI_LIBRARY variable if it is not a singleton case.

What could be the reason for this?

I tried to include the path to the mpi used in the program in the submition command but that didn't change anything.

Comment: you did not set the `I_MPI_PMI_LIBRARY` variable or you are running a singleton.

Comment: If you expect any help, you should at least post your slurm script.

Comment: I fixed it. I wasn't using a submit script that's why I didn't include it.